# Why won't oracle SQL developer launch debugger?

Tags: sql, oracle, debugging, stored-procedures

I have come here after searching in many different websites for a problem like the one I am facing.

**I have this huge procedure in an Oracle Database which I need to debug to find an error.**

After opening the procedure in Oracle SQL developer, I click on the gear icon, and "compile for debug" right after. Then I just click in the bug icon to start debugging.

On the bottom right of SQl developer screen appears a launching bar, but nothing else happens. In the connections section, where you can see the list of procedures, tables, etc... a green arrow appears before the name of the procedure I am trying to debug. It seems like it is preparing to start debugging, but it actually never starts. Below you can see a screenshot I took showing the issue.

[Screenshot showing the procedure I am trying to debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlHNP.png)

Here a screenshot of the "statement section" after clicking on "compile for debug"

[statement section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRwFL.png)

What I have tried:

- I have restarted the oracle server.
- I have tried to debug many others procedures, all of them have the same behavior.
- If I click on the "run" button, set the parameters and run the procedure, it will run, and give me the output variable.
- The procedure compiles without errors.
- Everything seems to be working just normal, except for debugging.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that it's blocking trying to connect to the DB for debugging, but isn't timing out, maybe because of firewall settings. If you click on the 'Statements - log' in the bottom-left of the IDE it'll expand that panel, and it may now have a tab for debugging which will - hopefully - show what it's trying to do. Maybe add that to the question. If it's showing it trying to connect to the wrong host and/or port, go to tools->preferences->debug and check the box next to 'prompt for debuggger host', and check the port range too.

Comment: you don't get the parameters dialog immediately after hitting the debug button?

Comment: Hey @AlexPoole,   I looked at this "Statement - log" window, and I posted it in the question above.  I saw that parameter PLSQL_DEBUG=false   Would that be the problem? I am trying to find out how to change that.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith  I do get the parameters dialog. I set the parameters, and right after that it's starts lauching, but never starts debugging.

Comment: @ArthurMedeiros - it wasn't really the statement log itself; when you show that do you see tabs along the bottom, particularly one for Debugging (probably with the bug icon)? (The message in that log probably isn't relevant; internal queries the IDE does are logged there too. But thatjeffsmith is going to be much more useful to you than I can be!)

Comment: I think I have just solved it.  After posting this question I started changing some parameters in the Listener.  I ended up shutting down the listener, and it took me almost 3 hours to reconfigure it.  The listener is working now (and it was working before), I decided to test the debugger again. Now it is debugging!!! Finally, now let me debug this HUGE procedure!  Thank you very much guys!

Answer (score 1):

I think I have just solved it. After posting this question I started changing some parameters in the Listener. I ended up shutting down the listener, and it took me almost 3 hours to reconfigure it. The listener is working now (and it was working before), I decided to test the debugger again. Now it is debugging!!! Finally, now let me debug that HUGE procedure! Thank you very much guys!